# Caching the last 3 values of a variable isn't working inside script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sed

My goal is to cache the value of a variable, going three times into history. So:

```
path=value3

cache1=value3
cache2=value2
cache3=value1

----------------

path=value4

cache1=value4
cache2=value3
cache3=value2
```

Now onto the script. The actual script is 4350 lines long, so this is a very simplified version. It just isn't possible to make it any more shorter, sorry.

```
path=/library/sections/1/all

a=0
while [[ $a = 0 ]]
do

#------------------------------
#caching the requests being made.
#When a new request is made:
        #[new->1]the new value goes to cache1
        #[1->2]the value of cache1 moves to cache2
        #[2->3]cache2 moves to cache3
        #[3->gone]cache3 disappears
#basically history/log of the last 3 requests.

cache1=/library/sections/1/all
cache2=
cache3=

#moving all the values one place down and adding the newest value to cache1

sed -i "s|^cache3=\S*|cache3=$cache2|" $filelocation/test.sh
sed -i "s|^cache2=\S*|cache2=$cache1|" $filelocation/test.sh
sed -i "s|^cache1=\S*|cache1=$path|" $filelocation/test.sh
#-----------------------------

#make api request and show output

GET http://$ipplexserver:32400$path?X-Plex-Token=$plexapitoken

#-------------------------------
#the read command, showing after the api output,  to switch between the movies and series output of the api.

if [[ $path = /library/sections/2/all ]]
then
        read -rp "exit | movies: " option

elif [[ $path = /library/sections/1/all ]]
then
        read -rp "exit | series: " option
fi
#--------------------------------

#--------------------------------
#depending on the option, you either exit or switch between movies and series output.

if [[ "$option" = movies ]]
then
        path=/library/sections/1/all

elif [[ "$option" = series ]]
then
        path=/library/sections/2/all

elif [[ "$option" = exit ]]
then
        a=1
fi
#-------------------------------

done
```

You get the api output of all the movies. You get the read command `exit | series:` . Choosing `series`, will change `path` to the endpoint for all the series and make the api request with the new `path` value. AKA switch between the series and the movies endpoints.

**What I expected**

```
path=/library/sections/1/all

cache1=/library/sections/1/all
cache2=
cache3=

----------------

path=/library/sections/2/all

cache1=/library/sections/2/all
cache2=/library/sections/1/all
cache3=
```

**What actually happens**

```
path=/library/sections/1/all

cache1=/library/sections/1/all
cache2=
cache3=

----------------

path=/library/sections/2/all

cache1=/library/sections/2/all
cache2=
cache3=

----------------

path=/library/sections/1/all

cache1=/library/sections/1/all
cache2=
cache3=
```

It replacesed the value of cache1 instead of moving it and taking it's place. I can't figure out why!

EDIT:
This did work. But the originl script mentioned above still doesn't.

```
cache1=test4
cache2=test3
cache3=test2

newvalue=test5
sed -i "s|^cache3=.*|cache3=$cache2|" $filelocation/test.sh
sed -i "s|^cache2=.*|cache2=$cache1|" $filelocation/test.sh
sed -i "s|^cache1=.*|cache1=$newvalue|" $filelocation/test.sh

-----------------

cache1=test5
cache2=test4
cache3=test3
```

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: I already used shellcheck. Aside from me not quoting all the variables, everything was fine.

Comment: *Inside* the loop, you set `cache1=/library/sections/1/all` and `cache2=` on every iteration; *then* you substitute `cache3=$cache2` and `cache2=$cache1`. So the only value that should change per iteration is `cache1`, which will contain the most recent value of `$path`

Comment: @steeldriver I moved cache1-3 outside of the loop. It now works differently, but still not how I want it. When I use the script, it still replaces the value of cache1 instead of moving. But when I exit the script and run it again, the exit-value of the previous run is moved to cache2 and cache1 is filled with the new "session". So instead of saving every value of `path`, it saves the value when exiting the script. It's caching the exit-value of `path`.

Comment: @steeldriver Do you have an idea because I truly don't know what's wrong.